# Cordova inAppBroser not working for WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, onsen-ui, inappbrowser

I'm using [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for `http`, `mailto` and `tel` like this:

**template**

```
<ons-list>
    <ons-list-item ng-click="myApp.writeTo()">email</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item ng-click="myApp.callTo()">call</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item ng-click="myApp.onWeb()">web</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

**controller**

```
function callTo()  { window.open('tel:+421123456789', '_system', 'location=yes'); }
function writeTo() { window.open('mailto:test@mail.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); }
function onWeb()   { window.open('http://www.google.sk', '_system'); }
```

**config.xml**

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

This is working correctly in Chrome on desktop and Android device, but in WP8 works only http. Cordova CLI version: `4.3.0`

Can anybody help me ?